# How does RingCT increase in transaction sizes affect people?

Tags: ringct

With the recent hardfork of RingCT there has been talk about the transaction sizes increasing to 25kb on average which is a lot more than before.

My question is how does that affect people? Does it affect greatly people who run a full node? Does it mean that the blockchain is going to be too big for most computers? Should the majority of people who have a wallet care about this and if so why?

Comment: A regular ringct transactions is about 12kb. only large transactions with many inputs and outputs have these huge transaction sizes.

Comment: The transaction size is mainly determined by the number of outputs. The number of inputs and mixin have smaller impact on the tx size. To be more precise, each output comes with a [range proof](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3035/in-ringct-how-are-the-rangeproofs-kept-seperate-from-the-pedersen-commitments-in/) using [Borromean ring signature](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2934/what-are-borromean-signatures) containing 64 pubkeys (representing commitments of all digits) and 2*64+1 scalars. This amounts to 193 instances of 32byte data, i.e. 6kB per output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, it only affect fees, which are a little higher. In term of disk space, it is  negligible (current blockchain size is ~10GB).

The little overhead for network traffic should largely be compensated by [fluffy blocks](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2633/what-are-fluffy-blocks).

Blockchain size is only one factor. What affects people who run a full node is [CONOP](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/20/what-does-conop-mean-and-how-does-it-relate-to-block-sizes-and-scaling).

Comment: Will the fees lower over time? People seem to be upset about the increase  in transaction fees. Will it stay that way, increase or decrease if solutions are found?

Comment: That deserves its own Q&A